# List view not showing results

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

My code is:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> trials1 { get; set; } = 
    new ObservableCollection<string> {"B1","B2","B3" };

public List<string> trials2 { get; set; } = new List<string> {"B555","B66666" };
```

When I use this binding syntax in list views everything works fine:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding trials1}" >           
</ListView>
```

But when I use this code, nothing appears. It just shows empty rows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding trials1}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding trials2}">                                
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>           
</ListView>
```

Does anyone have an explanation why this happens, and how to fix this issue?

Comment: check the space between trials and 2 in <Label Text="{Binding trials 2}"> .

Comment: i wrote it wrong ,fixed and edited the post it still showing empty rows

Comment: your label needs to be bound to a property of your ItemsSource.  Since your ItemsSource is a List<string>, you can only bind to the string itself.  Are you trying to build a nested ListView?

Comment: nested listed view ! nope thats way high level for me xD here is what i tried though  `public ObservableCollection<string> trials1 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>
 public ObservableCollection<string> trials2 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string> ` still showing empty rows

Comment: What do you expect to see in each row?

Comment: i did expect to see B555,B6666 and an empty third row cuz i thought in this case the list view will take the numbre of rows from my first Bindings in this case trials 1 then display labels in 3 rows depending  on the Second Binding in this case trials2 , thx for the help though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the BindingContext within the DataTemplate is different from the BindingContext for the ListView. When you bind to the ItemsSource property on a ListView, each item in the ListView has a BindingContext that is now the item it represents.

To run with your example:

```
ListView => the BindingContext is trials1, which contains "B1", "B2", and "B3"

    Item 0 is "B1" => the BindingContext is the object "B1" (which is a string in this case)
    Item 1 is "B2" => the BindingContext is the object "B2" (which is a string in this case)
    Item 2 is "B3" => the BindingContext is the object "B3" (which is a string in this case)
```

So your {Binding trials2} code is looking for a property named "trials2" on the objects "B1", "B2", and "B3". Since "B1", "B2", and "B3" are all strings, and a string object doesn't have a "trials2" property on it, it fails the binding and displays nothing.

To help illustrate what's happening with bindings, you can change your {Binding trials2} to be {Binding Length}, and your trials1 collection to contain "One", "More", and "Character". This will look at the Length property of the BindingContext, which in this case are strings, which have a Length property. You should get a ListView that displays 3, 4, and 9.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> trials1 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string> {"One","More","Character" };

...

 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding trials1}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Length}">                                
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>           
</ListView>
```

It is possible to override the BindingContext for specific elements, but in this case, it doesn't seem to make much sense to bind a collection of objects to a Label. It seems to be unclear what you are trying to do, but my answer given is why you're not seeing any output - your code is looking for properties that don't exist on the BindingContext.

For more details, you can see the [Bindings and Collections section of the MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics#bindings-and-collections).

I hope this helps!

Comment: i tried ur method and it did work , so i guess you are saying that my Second Bindings in this case `trials2` should be a property of my first Binding in this case ~trials1~ right ?

Comment: It all depends on what you're trying to achieve. With the example you gave, it's not obvious what you're trying to get to be displayed.

The key takeaway is that if you bind a CollectionView to a collection, the elements inside of the CollectionView are bound to items in your collection. From there, {Binding ...} will look for properties of the object it's bound to by default (it's BindingContext).

Comment: Here's another example:

public class Student { public string Name {get; set;} public int Age {get; set;} }

...

public List<Student> Students {get; set;} = new List<Student>()
{
    new Student() { Name = "Tom", Age = 10 },
    new Student() { Name = "Jerry", Age = 11}
}

...

If I bind a ListView to Students, each item in my ListView will be bound to a Student object. Then within my DataTemplate, I can bind to *properties of a Student*, which in this case would be either Name or Age => {Binding Name}

Comment: yup i get it now , i appreciate your help :)